# Why is for loop not working among the phrases listed in a line?

Tags: python

Perhaps this question is related to Python's grammar. Please excuse me.

Examples 1,2,4 work. However, Example 3 creates a grammar error.
In particular, examples 2 and 3 have exactly the same statement except that they were line up on single line using semicolons, so why doesn't example 3 work only?

```py
# example 1
import bpy
bpy.context.view_layer.cycles.use_denoising = True
```

```py
# example 2
import bpy
print("one line for loop")
for i in bpy.context.scene.view_layers : i.cycles.use_denoising = True
```

```py
# example 3
import bpy
print("one line for loop"); for i in bpy.context.scene.view_layers : i.cycles.use_denoising = True;
```

```py
# example 4
import bpy
vl = bpy.context.scene.view_layers; check = True;
print("one line multiple statment"); vl[0].cycles.use_denoising = check; vl[1].cycles.use_denoising = check; vl[2].cycles.use_denoising = check;
```

Comment: Not really a question about blender, but python syntax.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a generic python syntax question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolon cannot be used to separate [8. Compound statements — Python 3.8.6rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html). Only simple statement are allowed.

And the one-line for statement will probably confused with Comprehensions:

```
print(x) for x in range(20)  
print(x); for x in range(20): pass
```

[Why can't use semi-colon before for loop in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293128/why-cant-use-semi-colon-before-for-loop-in-python)

[bash - Python command line argument semicolon-loop error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602119/python-command-line-argument-semicolon-loop-error)